# Kotlin: For-loop must have an iterator method - is this a bug?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have the following code:

```
public fun findSomeLikeThis(): ArrayList<T>? {
    val result = Db4o.objectContainer()!!.queryByExample<T>(this as T) as Collection<T>
    if (result == null) return null
    return ArrayList(result)
}
```

If I call this like:

```
var list : ArrayList<Person>? = p1.findSomeLikeThis()

for (p2 in list) {
    p2.delete()
    p2.commit()
}
```

It would give me the error:

> For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` is of nullable type. So, you have to resolve this. There are several options:

```
for (p2 in list.orEmpty()) { ... }
```

or

```
 list?.let {
    for (p2 in it) {

    }
}
```

or you can just return an empty list

```
public fun findSomeLikeThis(): List<T> //Do you need mutable ArrayList here?
    = (Db4o.objectContainer()!!.queryByExample<T>(this as T) as Collection<T>)?.toList().orEmpty()
```

Comment: Alternatively list?.forEach {it.delete() ...}

Comment: `list?.forEach { ... }` handles the null (as mentioned above, just adding the code block around it)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
for(p2 in 0 until list.count()) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem when I loop on some thing it is not an array.
Example

```
fun maximum(prices: Array<Int>){
    val sortedPrices = prices.sort()
    for(price in sortedPrices){ // it will display for-loop range must have iterator here (because `prices.sort` don't return Unit not Array)

    }
}
```

This is different case to this question but hope it help

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen in Android when you read from shared preferences and are getting a (potentially) nullable iterable object back like `StringSet`. Even when you provide a default, the compiler is not able to determine that the returned value will never actually be null. The only way I've found around this is by asserting that the returned expression is not null using `!!` operator, like this:

```
val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
val searches = prefs.getStringSet("saved_searches", setOf())!!
for (search in searches){
    ...
}
```