# For Loop in kotlin

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin, Please help me in achieving this.

```
int number[] = {5,4,1,3,15}

for(int i = number.length; i > 0; i--)
{
   Log.e("number", number[i])
}
```

Comment: for (i in number.length downTo 1)
{
  Log.e("number", number[i])
}

Answer (score 88):

Try this

syntax of `for` loop in `Kotlin` is:

```
for (item in collection) {
    // body of loop
}
```

body

```
for (item: Int in ints) {
    // body of loop
}
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
for (i in 0..5) {
        println(i) // 0,1,2,3,4,5   --> upto 5
}
```

**OR**

```
 for (i in 0 until 5) {
        println(i) // 0,1,2,3,4    --> upto 4
 }
```

> for loop in array

```
var arr = arrayOf("neel", "nilu", "nilesh", "nil")

    for (item in arr)
    {
        println(item)
    }
```

> iterate through an array with an index.

```
 var arr = arrayOf("neel", "nilu", "nilesh", "nil")
for (item in arr.indices) {

        // printing array elements having even index only
        if (item%2 == 0)
            println(language[item])
    }
```

for more information check  **[`for loop in Kotlin`](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/for-loop)**

and this also **[`for loop in Kotlin`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)**

Comment: I need to have this `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)`. How can I convert to kotlin ?

Comment: @JohnJoe like this `for (i in 0..1) {
            Log.e("DATA", "DATA")
        }`

Comment: I tried this  `for(i in request?.locations.size) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ssss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }` but get `For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method`. `request?.locations.size` give me value 2.

Comment: @JohnJoe what is `request?.locations.size` here

Comment: It will return me value 2. You can assume it is value 2.

Comment: @JohnJoe check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201182/kotlin-for-loop-must-have-an-iterator-method-is-this-a-bug question for similar error

Answer (score 17):

Read [**`Control Flow Structure in Kotlin`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) .

> for (item in collection) print(item)

**`for`** loop iterates through anything that provides an iterator. This is equivalent to the **`foreach`** loop.

The body can be a block.

```
for (item: Int in ints) {
    // ...
}
```

**Try with**

```
val number = arrayOf(5, 4, 1, 3, 15)

    for (i in 0 until number.size)
    {
        Log.e("NUMBER", number[i].toString())
    }
```

Comment: Why we should be forced to remember extra stupid keywords...?

Answer (score 6):

**For Loops**

`for loop` iterates through anything that provides an iterator. This is equivalent to the foreach loop in languages like C#. The syntax is as follows:

```
for (item in collection) print(item)
```

The body can be a block.

```
for (item: Int in ints) {
    // ...
}
```

As mentioned before, for iterates through anything that provides an iterator, i.e.

has a member- or extension-function iterator(), whose return type
has a member- or extension-function next(), and
has a member- or extension-function hasNext() that returns Boolean.
All of these three functions need to be marked as operator.

A for loop over an array is compiled to an index-based loop that does not create an iterator object.

If you want to iterate through an array or a list with an index, you can do it this way:

```
for (i in array.indices) {
    print(array[i])
}
```

Note that this "iteration through a range" is compiled down to optimal implementation with no extra objects created.

Alternatively, you can use the withIndex library function:

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

for more info [see link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1:**

```
     var number= arrayOf(1, 2, 3 4,5)

            for (item in number)

Log.e("number", item)
```

**Case 2**

```
 var number= arrayOf(1, 2, 3 4,5)
    for (item in number.indices) {
    // printing array elements 

Log.e("number", language[item])
        }
```